# How to invert a specific SELECT in MySQL (WordPress database)

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have the following SELECT that returns all users that posted something in WordPress:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM qa_posts)
```

Which SELECT would do the opposite? (return all users that never posted)

NOT IN didn't work!

=================

```
SELECT * FROM `wp_users` WHERE 1
```

Showing rows 0 - 191 ( 192 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM qa_posts)
```

Showing rows 0 - 86 ( 87 total, Query took 0.0012 sec)

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM qa_posts)
```

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0055 sec)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything more complex than just saying NOT?

```
SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT userid FROM qa_posts)
```

Ok, try this as an alternative

```
SELECT u.*
FROM wp_users u
LEFT JOIN qa_posts p on u.id = p.userid
WHERE p.userid is null;
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Comment: Then you have no user in wp_users that are not in qa_posts.

Comment: Try the left anti join statement, see what that comes back with.

Comment: YES! IT WORKS! Showing rows 0 - 104 ( 105 total, Query took 0.0133 sec). thank you!